# Calculate test coverage percentage only using coverage.py to create gitlab badge using anybadge

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci, code-coverage, coverage.py

Gitlab only provides to visualize the [coverage.py](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.5/) report for the default branch using a hard-coded logic: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#test-coverage-report-badge

As I want to get the coverage value for any branch and show it in the `README.MD` using the [anybadge](https://github.com/jongracecox/anybadge) package, I only want to get the total test coverage as percentage in order to create the badge manually and provide it as an artifact.

How can I only calculate this total coverage percentage similar to gitlab's logic using [coverage.py](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.5/)?

Any hints are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `coverage json` command to get a JSON file with the results, then extract the total to use with anybadge.  Share the code when you get it working!